# Django multiple repeating dropdowns

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am repeating a Django Form dropdown as follow:

**html**

```
    <form class="form-group" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.X1}}
      {{ form.X1}}
    </form>
```

where,

**model.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    X1 = models.ForeignKey(otherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**form.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I submit the form, I only see one instance of `X1` being returned to my `view`. I don't see the second `X1` value...

**How can I pass the second `X1` as well?**

Comment: Please check the request's body with a browsers developer tools to see if both values are being included.

Comment: Good suggestion. I did that and found that they both have the same ```id``` which would explain a few other questions I have, but it may also be informative to this particular matter. What do you make of it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#id1) `request.POST['key']` will return the last value if there are more than one. If you want all of them, you need to use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Comment: Sorry I am growing into the docs still, not sure what ```key``` is here. Please spell it out for me..

Answer (score 0):

Please use request.POST.getlist('key') with key being the "name" of the input (should be "X1").